# Add handler in single jetty-server

Tags: logging, jetty

I use org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler

but this handler logging only:

> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -  -  [04/θών/2014:08:16:27 +0000] "GET
>   /CardTransfer-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/transf HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"

**I need to logging all request body in output and input request** (JSON and so on..)

Please give me solution about how this could work

Answer (score 0):

http://logback.qos.ch/access.html#jetty

It helped for me.. Maybe will help to someone else